# How do I sort my Calendar by Start Date using FreeMarker?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, freemarker

I have created an [**application display template**](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/6-2/using-application-display-templates) (ADT) in *Liferay* for the Calendar and I want to sort the list ordered by **startDate**. From the Asset Publisher configuration I can sort only by "Create Date", "Modified Date", "Publish Date" and "Expiration Date".
To order by "Start Date" or "End Date" I have to do it programmatically.
I am using **FreeMarker** as language and I tried as follows:

```
<#assign calService = utilLocator.findUtil("calendar-portlet", "com.liferay.calendar.service.CalendarBookingLocalService") />
<#list entries?sort_by("startDate") as curEntry>
    <#assign calBookingEntry = calService.getCalendarBooking(curEntry.getAssetRenderer().getClassPK()) />
    <#assign startTime = getterUtil.getLong(calBookingEntry.getStartTime()) />
    <#assign endTime = getterUtil.getLong(calBookingEntry.getEndTime()) />
    <div>
        <h2>${calBookingEntry.getTitle(locale)}</h2>
        <p>${calBookingEntry.getDescription(locale)}</p>
    </div>
</#list>
```

But I get this error.

```
?sort_by(...) failed at sequence index 0: The "startDate" subvariable was not found.
```

Then I checked what are the key-value pairs in the hash:

```
{
    entryId=21374,
    groupId=20182,
    companyId=20155,
    userId=20199,
    userName=Test Test,
    createDate=Tue Jun 21 15:12:06 GMT 2016,
    modifiedDate=Fri Aug 12 12:59:41 GMT 2016,
    classNameId=20440,
    classPK=21370,
    classUuid=c4b0008d-ba07-4f63-a858-3f5f4f0fff08,
    classTypeId=0,
    visible=true,
    startDate=null,
    endDate=null,
    publishDate=null,
    expirationDate=null,
    mimeType=text/html,
    title=title tes,
    description=Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris id tortor at odio elementum auctor non ut orci.,
    summary=Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris id tortor at odio elementum auctor non ut orci. ,
    url=,
    layoutUuid=,
    height=0,
    width=0,
    priority=0.0,
    viewCount=0
}
```

and I noticed that the `startDate` key has no value (**null**), but in the database table <sup>[table: `CalendarBooking`, column: `startTime`]</sup> has this value: `1468022400000`

Comment: Where is your `entries` defined?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337681/freemarker-template-sort-by-one-or-other

Comment: @ParkashKumar `entries` represents the list of assets that will be displayed through the template and it uses [AssetEntry class](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/asset/model/AssetEntry.html)

Comment: The entries are defined in the calendar portlet. I added events in the calendar and I filled the Title, Start Date and End Date fields and I selected yes in "Attend?". Then I created a template for the Asset Publisher to display a list of events added in the calendar portlet and sorted by Start Date, but the sorting doesn't work.

Comment: First of all `startDate` of `assetentry` is not same as `startTime` of `calendarbooking`.

Comment: And second, `calService.getCalendarBooking` returns `CalendarBooking` object, why it is returning `AssetEntry` object?

Comment: Because I am using Asset Publisher and it needs AssetEntry to display the list of items. How do I use `startTime` to sort `entries`?

Comment: Does `entries` contain all the actual data of `CalendarBooking` modal?

Comment: @ParkashKumar no. I have to use `calBookingEntry` to get the data.